# After adding the data to a list in one section, how it is reflecting in all the other section in flutter?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, I have created one json with nested objects, I am trying to add the values in one list of particular section, After executing the add to list line, while debugging I can able to see, that the data is added to all other sections as well. Below is my code snippet. Can someone help.

`procedureResultSet[kProcedureResult]!.skip(3).first[kProcedureSections][sectionOrder][kValues][subIndex][measureLabel][lesionLocation][lesionMainLabel].add(indexedLesionResults);`

procedureResultSet is my json contains the procedureSections as List, Here I am trying add in this indexed `sectionOrder` list values. My List is located in this place `lesionMainLabel`. After executing this line, it is reflecting in all the other sections 'all sectionOrder'